# Keep instance of activity when call this activity second time

Tags: android

I have an Main activity. Main activity call other activity (A) by startActivityForResult. Go to A. I search something and have a list item. Then click one item in A return to Main. Then call A 2nd time. A list disappear. I think a new instance of A is created. I want to call old instance of A and keep list item.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` on the Intent before you start activity A. That way it will use the existing instance if one exists on the activity stack